# Call methods of fields in xdocreport

Tags: java, xdocreport

I' am new to xdocreport. I have an util class *Formatter* to format report values. I add instance of my class to context and want to call method of Formatter class passing another field as argument.

I tried to use `«$formatter.dateFormat($insurance.INSURANCE_DATE)»` 
but it does not work.

Does xdocreport support this feature or I can only format value in java code?

Comment: "but it does not work", what is your problem (stack trace, null value, etc)? Which template engine are you using (Freemarker, Velocity?)

Comment: I'am using Velocity. There are no errors, when I'am generating report, String  «$formatter.dateFormat($insurance.INSURANCE_DATE)» is not changing and printing as in template. There is no problem with printing «$insurance.INSURANCE_DATE».

Comment: Please share your project in github, it will be more easy to help you.

Comment: Angelo, here example that I use  https://github.com/rmorenko/neoflex.git

Comment: Your docx which declares «$formatter.dateFormat(«$test.CurrentDate»)» must be embedded inside a mergefiled (like your $test.Name). Please create a mergefield with «$formatter.dateFormat(«$test.CurrentDate»)» content and hope it should work